# Templating engine for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, templating, templating-engine

Does anyone know any templating engine that works under .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the terminology, but could you suggest some templating engine equivalents on the full .NET Framework? That makes it easier to be able to suggest any availability of such frameworks on .NET CF.

Comment: Sure. .NET full framework templating engines samples: NVelocity, StringTemplates.